# Making two colored div responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm working in two colored banner that is going to be on top of my website, the problem is that the right part is not responsive, I have tried giving it %, rem, px, and vw, but nothing seems to work. This is my code, as you can see the blue part takes way too much width and the mail cannot stay fixed.
How can I make for the blue part to occupy the rest of the div

```css
.banner {
  margin-top: 0%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #c5027f;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  width: 50%;
  position:relative; 
}

.banner:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height: 1px;
  top:0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #009ee2;
  border-right: 40px solid #009ee2;
  width: 134rem;
  z-index:-1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <p style="color: white; float: left; font-size: .65em;margin-left: 10px;">54466565</p></i>
   <p style="margin-left: 177%; margin-top: -5%; color: white; z-index: -1;">contacto@promedics.mx</p>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd simply use a gradient background image (and the CSS drops to this lines) :

```css
.banner {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#c5027f+50,009ee2+50 */
  background: #c5027f; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #c5027f 50%, #009ee2 50%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #c5027f 50%,#009ee2 50%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #c5027f 50%,#009ee2 50%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c5027f', endColorstr='#009ee2',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.banner p {
  padding: 16px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.banner p.email {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <p class="tel">54466565</p>
  <p class="email">contacto@promedics.mx</p>
</div>
```

(Thanks to [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/))

Answer (score 0):

I think that your way to do that isn't the best. But example solution to do that is:

```
<div class="banner">
        <p style="color: white; float: left; font-size: .65em">54466565</p></i>
        <p style="color: white; float: right; font-size: .65em;margin-right: -100%; ">contacto@promedics.mx</p>
    </div>
```

However, I suggest to create two divs, half of content and in the middle add maybe triangle of second color. There are many better way to implement this. You can also rotate second one with overflow hidden on container and rotate back content.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest
Display:inline-block;

On both paragraph tags.
Also I don't know if you noticed but you have a random ending  which may be rendering and messing up your styles.
Try to avoid floats at all costs.